# jQuery: target 3rd element of every 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to target the 3rd `.foo` element of every 6. Below, a small illustration of what I mean:

```
1
2
3 (this)
4
5
6
1
2
3 (this)
4
5
6
and so on...
```

As far as I've got is this which merely targets every 3rd element, but this isn't quite right as it's also targeting the first `.foo` as well: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/Bb4Hv/

```
$('.foo').each(function() {

    if(!($('.foo').index(this) % 3)) {

        $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }

});
```

Any suggestions on how it might be possible to achieve what I've illustrated would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The 1-6 are in the same div, or differents?

Comment: @Freak_Droid seems I forgot to put the jsFiddle link in, duhhh. Now added, here too: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/Bb4Hv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally like the `nth-child()` approach better (as suggested by @Arbel), but a minor change to your question code  to get it to work would be:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {    
    if(!(($('.foo').index(this)-2) % 6)) {    
        $( this ).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }    
});
```

after all, you actually want every 6th element, just starting offset by 2

and as a minor side note, the jQuery function each, actually passes in the index and element (native element) to the iterator function anyway, so you could change the above to

```
$('.foo').each(function(i,ele) {
    if(!((i-2) % 6)) {
       $(ele).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

I mentioned that I liked the `nth-child` approach better, but judging by some of the comments, perhaps `nth-of-type` may suit your requirement better.

Links FYI:

[Mozilla nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type)

and

[CSS Tricks comparison of the two](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Example with `nth-of-type`

```
.foo:nth-of-type(6n-3)
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**NOTE**: *the reason for the difference in the formula to establish the element you want (i.e. i-2 % 6 or 6n-3), is that javascript starts with index 0 as the first element, CSS starts with 1 (for the n in nth-child or nth-of-type selectors)*

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `nth-child(6n-3)`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/F2D4V/2/

With jQuery:

```
$('.foo:nth-child(6n-3)').css("background-color", "red");
```

Your fiddle updated with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/Bb4Hv/1/

Comment: this only target type not class though, thus if there are siblings in there of a different class it won't work. I just want to target the `.foo` class.

Comment: He is correct. All li elements are counted in nth-child, not just the .foo ones. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/F2D4V/4/)